# Network Bridge in Windows 8

Tags: networking, virtualbox, home-networking, windows-8

In Windows 7 i bridged my ethernet connection and the Host Only Adapaters of my VirtualBox VMS to gain access to the Internet through the Network Bridge and the VMS were part of my LAN.

My Setup was like this:

```
bridge                   192.168.0.1
eth0 on my pc            192.168.0.2
VM1(hostonly adapter)    192.168.0.3
VM2(hostonly adapter)    192.168.0.4
```

In Windows 8 it seems that i can't access the Internet through the Bridge, the status of the bridge is "connected" but when i click on the network connection icon it shows only the ethernet controller and the hostonly adapters with "limited connection".

How can i force Windows 8 to use the Network Bridge ?

Comment: did you do this manually in the control panel, or did you do it through virtual box?

Comment: i created the bridge manually in the control pannel

Comment: do it through the Virtual Box options. It will set all that up automatically for you.

Comment: I've experienced this problem as well, except when trying to bridge the Hyper-V network adapter.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, as Taylor Gibb wrote above, is to remove your external interface from any Microsoft Bridge Adaptor, and configure bridging in VirtualBox. Bridging to wireless adaptors is special, and the Microsoft Bridge adaptor can't do it properly. (You can only transmit on a single MAC address on a wireless interface, the one you associated with).

You won't even see the wireless adaptor in VirtualBox unless you remove it from any bridges that it's a member of.